# Docker Image Window Core pull fails?

Tags: docker

I did try to find some Window image officially by Microsoft without success.
Surprise that Wwindow image 2019 recently works for most basic concept testing but now it is over.
For an examples: https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/containers/windows-server-2019-now-available/ba-p/382430
See the errors
docker pull mcr.microsoft.com/windows/servercore:1809
Error response from daemon: no match for platform in manifest: not found

It does not happen to Linux/Ubuntu core.
Why a big business??

Regards

Comment: https://mcr.microsoft.com/en-us/product/windows/servercore/tags still list it.   Are you using an unsupported platform?

Comment: Hi Andersen, thks much for comment. I ran on Docker Desktop under Window 11 Ent/ using PS command , see this official release did not work: https://hub.docker.com/_/microsoft-windows-servercore docker pull mcr.microsoft.com/windows/servercore:ltsc2019
Error response from daemon: no match for platform in manifest: not found

Comment: I tried most of image here: https://mcr.microsoft.com/v2/windows/tags/list see it had no success at all docker pull mcr.microsoft.com/windows/servercore:20H2-amd64
20H2-amd64: Pulling from windows/servercore
99cf2a8aa05b: Download complete
..
failed to extract layer 4: link /var/lib/containerd-stargz-grpc/snapshotter/snapshots/1543/fs/Files/Program Files/Common Files/Microsoft Shared/Ink/en-US/micaut.dll.mui /var/lib/containerd-stargz-grpc/snapshotter/snapshots/1543/fs/Files/Program Files (x86)/Common Files/Microsoft Shared/ink/en-US/micaut.dll.mui: no such file or directory: unknown

Comment: Do you have any antivirus program active?

Comment: Actually it looks like your windows installation is broken. Try uninstalling and reinstalling docker desktop

Comment: I re-Create Wwindow 10 Disable antivirus. Turnoff firewall..All are retried coming failed. It seems something stuck with business image??

Comment: What cpu are you using?

Comment: I use PC - Intel Xeon E3 1245 Skylake Socket 1151 LGA - 14nm. Code: CPU E3-1245 v5 @ 3.5GHz.

Comment: So not arm.  I would suggest disabling your antivirus and reinstall docker desktop and then try again.